# Can We send data using exisiting power outlets in homes

Tags: power-supply, power, data, power-line-communication

I am trying to build a project in which I want to transfer data through existing power outlets in a home through power lines while simultaneously using those outlets for power supply also.
My question Is it possible? and if yes where and how can I explore more about this topic.
 something like this http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-PA4020PKIT

Comment: What kind of data? Why not just use existing ethernet-over-power like you point to in your question?

Comment: I want to send just ON-OFF state data about the power outlet in a home where there is no ethernet available

Answer (score 3):

[X-10 is a system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_%28industry_standard%29) developed nearly 40 years ago (1975) which is designed to send control information over the power line to turn devices on and off, etc.  It consists of controllers (transmitters) and receivers.  Being so old, you can find hundreds if not thousands of devices on eBay that you could hack.  Of course you can also buy new ones too from many suppliers.

There is even a [library for Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/x10) that allows it to send and receive X-10 commands.

And here is an [application note](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00236a.pdf) showing how to do X-10 with a PIC16.

Comment: Have you ever tried looking for "X10" on eBay? "1,004,885 results for X10"

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle Yes, but I figured most of those weren't valid hits so I reduced my expectation to thousands to be more realistic.  And there would only be so many devices that would be suitable for the OP to modify (i.e. he probably doesn't want light sockets, or dimmer switches, etc.)

Comment: The problem is, searching for anything X10 results in finding everything where there is ten of them, or has 10mm/cm/m/in etc in one dimension... it's almost impossible to find what you want. eg, searching "x10 socket" gives you lots of bolts.  10,000+ results, and I got bored looking through them and found 1 actual X10 device. It's an impossible term to search for.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle Did you try X-10 or "X-10"?

Comment: Yep. 10,976 bolts.  The exact phrase ""X-10 socket" = ~800 bolts, 3 relays, and a few other bits if you trawl through.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle But if you click on eBay's suggested link under the search bar, "X-10 lamp socket" you get a page of items which are a little more relevant.  Agree, there is still the problem of x10 being "ten times".  eBay also suggested several other searches, like X-10 home automation, X-10 mini controller, x-10 transceiver etc. which are a lot more focused.

Comment: I managed to get it locked into a home automation section for searches at last - yes, it narrows it down somewhat. 82 results for x10 now, much more reasonable.  Not easy to do though.

Comment: Be careful... X-10 lamp modules will destroy non-dimmable electronic bulbs (CFLs, LEDs), and ALL known non-Insteon X-10 "appliance" modules  malfunction with them too. This includes the "high-power" appliance modules that use real relays (the "flip the power switch to toggle power locally" feature can't be disabled by cutting a jumper, so CFLs will spontaneously turn on, and LEDs will blink every time the module polls the power switch state unless you add an incandescent night light in parallel). I've heard Insteon's newest modules fix the problem... but Insteon modules aren't cheap.